# Change where jQuery scrollTop stops?

Tags: jquery

In the code below, the page scroll to the section tag with the id of `#section-start`. Since my page contains several sections tags, I have a 150px top padding to get some space between them. But the top padding is also where the scrolling stops. Is there a way to reduce the top padding with something like 100px just when it scroll so that the content of the section tag is closer to the top of the view in the browser? Is there a way to add -100px in the code below?

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#section-start").offset().top
}, scrollSpeed);
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle for us to work out the problem

Comment: How about just adding some space: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#section-start").offset().top + 100
}, scrollSpeed);`

Comment: @Miro Thanks! Simple solution that worked perfect!